# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(' - PIG, CentOs

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to execute the following command in pig

```
7369,SMITH,CLERK,800.00,null,20
7499,ALLEN,SALESMAN,1600.00,300.00,30
```

Script

```
emp_bag = LOAD '/home/training/dvs/emp.csv' using PigStorage(',') AS (eno:int, ename:chararray, job:chararray, sal:int, comm:int, deptno:int);
```

And getting the below error

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Please help to resolve this.

Comment: Post sample data from emp.csv.The syntax looks correct

Comment: Here is sample data-

7369,SMITH,CLERK,800.00,null,20

Comment: I don't see any issue with the sample snippet shared.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running your pig command on bash ?

If yes, please start the pig console first and then run it.

Just type pig and enter.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue is the data of type float.You need to change the datatype for 4th and 5th field to float from int.
Also if null is a string then you will have to handle it using chararray field and replace 'null' with ''.

```
emp_bag = LOAD '/home/training/dvs/emp.csv' using PigStorage(',') AS (eno:int, ename:chararray, job:chararray, sal:float, comm:float, deptno:int);
```

Alternatively,you can check whether the issue is with the datatype by not specifying the schema in which case the default datatype will be bytearray.

```
emp_bag = LOAD '/home/training/dvs/emp.csv' using PigStorage(',')
```

Comment: No Luck. Tried, it did not work :( .
Is there any special character issue here?

Comment: why do you have a null in your text file? Use chararray for those fields since float cannot accept 'null'

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't activated the grunt shell.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."